# Ember Query Params unset Query Parameter

Tags: ember.js

I am using the new Ember Query Parameters and having issues "unsetting" a query parameter.

I have a scenario where I need to navigate from something like: ?game=13 to ?question=14.
This means that I have 2 query parameters on my router: game, question. Unfortunately this transition (coming from ?game=13):

```
this.transitionToRoute({queryParams: {question: 14}} );
```

This unfortunately leads to :

> ?game=13&question=14.

I have also tried:

```
this.transitionToRoute({queryParams: {question: 14, game: null}} );
```

which leads to:

> ?game=null&question=14

Because somehow everything is stringtransformed.

How can I transition to ?question=14 and remove the game query parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your properties storing query params to some value. Set them back to this initial value to remove them from your URL later:

```
App.SomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    queryParams: ['myParam'],
    myParam: "initial",

    ...
);
```

Later...

```
controller.set('myParam', "initial");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a default value for your query param in the controller. After that you could do:

```
this.transitionToRoute({queryParams: {question: 14, game: <the default value that you set in the controller>}} );
```

Comment: This is not working, because the default value is null. But when I provide null as value it is transformed into "null" (as string) and then I get: ?game=null&question=14

Comment: Try "" instead of null. Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
var params = {};
if(this.get('controller.question') params.question = this.get('controller.question');
if(this.get('controller.game') params.game = this.get('controller.game');

this.transitionToRoute({queryParams: params} );
```